# How do you change text in a header for a certain period of time in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>5</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stage.css" />

<script src="jslibs/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).click(function(event) {
     var x = event.offsetX,
     y = event.offsetY;

     $('#player').animate({
         top: y,
         left: x
     }, 1000);

     $('#change').html('hello');
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
<h1 id="change">Mario is standing still...</h1>
</div>
<div id="stage">
<img id="player" src="images/mario.gif" alt="Mario" />
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

That is my code, but when i click it just changes it to hello permenantly, I want it to only change to hello for 1000ms.  I have been looking all around the jqueryAPI, google, anywhere.  I just cannot get it to happen.  Anyone have any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried changing it back with a setTimeout()?
setTimeout(function(){$('#change').html('');},3000)

Answer (score 2):

You just need to wrap a reset of what you are doing in a setTimeout

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
 var x = event.offsetX,
 y = event.offsetY;

 $('#player').animate({
     top: y,
     left: x
 }, 1000);

 var original = $('#change').html();
 $('#change').html('hello');
 setTimeout(function(){
     $('#change').html(original);
 }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) function to delay the command:

```
$('#change').html('hello');
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#change').html('Mario is standing still...');
}, 1000);
```

That function is part of native JavaScript, it doesn't have anything to do with jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

try this code instead of the current line

```
    $('#change').html('hello').delay(1000).html('Mario is standing still...');
```

altenatively if the value of "Mario is standing still..." is something that changes you could use

```
    var originalText = $('#change').html();
    $('#change').html('hello').delay(1000).html(originalText);
```